# Are these inversions correct and have the same meaning?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> He came, and in such very good time, that the ladies were none of them
>   dressed. **In ran Mrs. Bennet to her daughter’s room**, in her
>   dressing-gown, and with her hair half finished, crying out,
>
> “My dear Jane, make haste and hurry down. He is come—Mr. Bingley is
>   come. He is, indeed. Make haste, make haste. Here, Sarah, come to Miss
>   Bennet this moment, and help her on with her gown. Never mind Miss
>   Lizzy’s hair.”
>
> *from Pride & Prejudice* by Jane Austen

I could get the meaning of the sentence, and I understand it as an "inversion“，often seen in literature.

My question is that if all the following versions are the same meaning and grammatically ok:

1. **In ran** Mrs. Bennet **to** her daughter’s room
2. **In to ran** Mrs. Bennet her daughter’s room
3. **Into ran** Mrs. Bennet her daughter’s room
4. **Into** her daughter’s room **ran** Mrs. Bennet

Could someone help? Thanks.

Comment: You should only ask a single question. *In running* means something totally different than *in ran*. (1) *In running to her room, Mrs. Bennet tripped and fell.* (2) *In ran Mrs. Bennet, entering her room in haste.* Not only can't you simply replace one with the other without adjusting the rest of the words, what they describe is different—so you would change the meaning too. Everything else being equal, sentence inversion is fine. Either version works. But what single question are you actually focused on here? The two are not really related to each other.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying, because I tried my best to illustrate the confusion with me. What you said confused me more, because " Mrs. Bennet didn't trip or fall”.

Comment: I changed my question, see if it would clarify my confusion with the sentence.

Comment: As I said, *in running* means something different than *in ran*. *In running* means *in the process of running*, while *in ran* means *ran into*. My use of *tripping* was meant to illustrate the difference in meaning. You cannot simply replace one phrase with the other. (But I see you're no longer concerned with that particular difference.)

Comment: Thanks. I see now. I was confused by the use of "a past tense after a preposition", as in "in ran". but as you explained, and with the other' help,  in this case "in ran" means "ran into".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) and (4) work as sentences, (2) and (3) don't. I suppose it's because *into* needs to come immediately before the name of the place being entered.

Comment: If (1) and (4) is acceptable, does it mean in this case, that "in to" ="into"?

Comment: There would be no reason to leave a space between them in this context.

Comment: that's what I am trying to say and confused me most. if to put the sentence back in normal order, shouldn't it be "Mrs. Bennet ran into her daughter’s room"? if "into" is the only correct, then why the original sentence put "In" in the beginning of the sentence? really struggling here....

Comment: It's a stylistic choice. Obviously 'Mrs. B. ran into her daughter's room' would be the normal way to say it, but putting the preposition at the start of the sentence makes the action seem more lively. Another example - "Up jumped Dingo - Yellow-Dog-Dingo" (Kipling)

Comment: I get the effect of inversion totally. You didn't get my question. As you said, （2）is not acceptable, （3）is not acceptable, and there is no reason to leave a space between "into"--- the sentence should only use "into" not "in to", so,  therefore, how could it be ok to break down “into" to "in to", as in sentence (1)?

Comment: if（1）and (4) are right and have the same meaning, then isn't  "into" equal "in to"， in this case only?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I said there was no reason to leave a space in this context, not that it was always wrong to do so. In the rather unusual case of Jane Austen's inverted sentence, _in_ and _to_ have to be separated because _into ran Mrs. Bennet_ doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for patience and time. I understand it's not the first time you helped. Again thank you for your tolerance with my stubbornness.